# How to request access to AppDiagnosticInfo after being denied?

Tags: uwp, system.diagnostics, desktop-bridge

Is there a way to ask for permission again? I never get the prompt again after pressing no. If there is no way to prompt for it again, what is the proper way of handling it? Should I make a popup stating that the user needs to enable it in the settings? Or should I just redirect them to the settings app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a system behavior, and is not specific to this permission. Once a permission is denied by the user, the system does not prompted the dialog again but raise an AccessDenied exception instead when the permission is requested subsequently.

For better UX, I would choose to display a dialog explaining the permission needs to be granted, then redirect the user to the specific Settings page once she clicks the OK button.